# RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered error in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the next warning by matplotlib:

```
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  """
```

This is my sample of code, which causes this warning:

```
...

def s_2(X):
    over_X_2 = np.cumsum(X**2)/n_
    over_2_X = (np.cumsum(X)/n_)**2
    return (over_X_2 - over_2_X)

def mean(X):
    return np.cumsum(X)/n_

ga_alpha = 10
ga_beta = 20

Gamm = sps.gamma(a=ga_alpha, scale=1/ga_beta).rvs(size=N)

ga_alpha_est = mean(Gamm)**2/s_2(Gamm)
ga_beta_est = mean(Gamm)/s_2(Gamm)


pylab.ylim(0, 30)
# g_est_alpha = 
# norm_est_sigm = get_s_sqr
plt.plot(n_, ga_beta_est)

...
```

I understand, that this is just a warning, and this is not a big deal to ignore it, but I'm wondering why does this thing appear, and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a warning, but it's a warning that's raised because it encountered a divide by zero. Perhaps `n_` or `over_X_2 - over_2_X` has a value of `0`? Printing debug messages really helps here.